# Hibernate @AttributeOverride has no effect

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the folloing entity structure.

```
@Entity
public class A {

@Embedded 
private B b;
...
}

@Embeddable
public B{
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "product", column = @Column(name = "gdb_product") )})
@Embedded private C c;
...
}

@Embeddable
public C{
private String product;
...
}
```

But the @AttributeOverride hasn't any effect because the in the db hasn't changed.

used jar : 
hierbenate 4.3.10-Final,
hsqldb 2.3.1

Comment: And if I add a new embedded type with the same type for instance @Embedded private cc and overrided column is fdb_prdocukt than thow an exception:  Repeated column in mapping for entity: A column: produkt (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Answer (score 0):

The column name will be change from "product" to "gdb_product".

if you don't use

> @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "product", column =
>   @Column(name = "gdb_product") )})

then column will be "product"